# Advanced indexing in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays: `A` such that `A.shape = (N, M, K)` and `index` such that `index.shape = (N, M)`. As a result I want to get such array `B` that `B[i, j] = A[i, j, index[i, j]]`. How to achieve that in the simplest way?

One solution that comes to my mind is that we can do it like this:
`B = A.reshape(-1, K)[np.arange(N * M), index.reshape(-1)].reshape(N, M)`. I wonder if there are any other solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `2D` extended range array for the first axis that aligns with the shape of the indexing array `index` and hence use [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing), like so -

```
B = A[np.arange(N)[:,None], np.arange(M), index]
```

Comment: Hint: broadcasting (N,1),(M,),(N,M) -> (N,1),(1,M),(N,M) -> (N,M)